# Redirect url conainig part of the old url

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect this

```
/transfer/destination/transfer-loc1-to-loc2
```

to

```
https://test.com/locatins/part-loc1-to-loc2
```

So basically I want to have loc1 and loc2 copy to the new url. 
loc1 and loc2 are not constant. 
How can I do this? With 301 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following rule in your htaccess (in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^transfer/destination/transfer-([^/]+)$ https://test.com/locatins/part-$1 [R=301,L]
```